# Can't get wireless on macbook pro 8,2

Tags: wireless, drivers, broadcom, macbook-pro

I'm a linux Newb, and I have tried several of the fixes listed to try and get my wifi drivers to work, but to no avail. Does anyone here know why this isn't working for me, or better yet, how to fix it?

Under `lspci -vvv` I get the following output:

```
03:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Corporation BCM4331 802.11a/b/g/n (rev 02)
    Subsystem: Apple Inc. AirPort Extreme
    Control: I/O- Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
    Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- SERR- 
    Kernel modules: bcma
```

With `sudo lshw -class network` I get this output:

```
  *-network UNCLAIMED
       description: Network controller
       product: BCM4331 802.11a/b/g/n
       vendor: Broadcom Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       version: 02
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:b0600000-b0603fff
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Try to look here:
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=12042532

And also here:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MacBookPro8-2/Oneiric